# Imported android project to Eclipse: Cant compile

Tags: android, eclipse, compiler-errors

I have imported a project to Eclipse. The version of the API was 15 and it compiled successfully, but I needed 7th because on my phone the OS cannot be updated. After changing the version of the Android API to older one (7th) I can't compile the project, the follwing errors occures:

```
import android.hardware.usb.UsbConstants;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
```

It says R cannot be resolved to a variable:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

And in main.xml

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

it says:  String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent').

Is it possible to resolve this errors, but still using the old API version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the USB functionality: No. It exists since [API level 12](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html).

Comment: Is it possible to implement the USB driver by myself? For example the Andoid USB is successfully used for SD Card access. Isn't it done through the Andoid OS, if so, the only thing to do is the driver, am I right?

Comment: No. From the viewpoint of a Dalvik (Java) application these capabilities are baked-in. You would need to have to patch the OS. Note thhat the SD card access lets the Android device work as USB slave whereas the android.hardware.usb package offers methods for working as USB host which is quite different.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile your project with the latest Android Api.
Project Properties -> Android -> Android 4.0

In the manifest, you can set the

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

If you are not using any library or new feature, it should work.

Comment: I did as you said, the program compiled and was successfully installed on my device, however when I tried to run it, it has stopped unexpectedly.

Comment: may be you are using some classes/methods that are not supported by the version 7 of the sdk !

Answer (score 0):

Add the Jar of API 15 from platforms folder and include in Android MAnifesh as Android minsdk as 9 and target sdk as 15 then i hope your app will run